# Improve performance using lua and Roblox Studio

Tags: performance, lua, lag, roblox, heartbeat

I have finally finished my first script using lua and Roblox studio.
The goal was to have a set of tiles change colour when the player steps on it.

Here is my code:

```
local parts = {}
for k, v in pairs(game.Workspace:GetDescendants()) do
    if string.sub (v.name, 1, 4) == "Part"  then
        table.insert(parts, v)
    end
end

local char = workspace:WaitForChild("localPlayer") 

local hrp = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")

local newThread = coroutine.create(function()

game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    local charpos = hrp.Position

    for k, v in pairs (parts)do
        if (charpos - v.CFrame.Position).magnitude <= 6 then
            local pos = v.CFrame.Position
            for k, v in pairs(parts) do
                if v.CFrame.Position.X == pos.X or v.CFrame.Position.Z == pos.Z then
                    v.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
                    print("touching")
                end
            end
            return
        else
            v.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Medium stone grey")
            print("not touching")
        end
    end
end)

end)

coroutine.resume(newThread)
```

This works:

[image]

But my project needs more tiles and more colors. When I increase the number of platforms etc.. the program becomes very laggy.

[image]

The gif doesn't really show how laggy, but it gets worse and worse and after about a minute of playing you can hardly control the player effectively.

As you can see, I tried putting my function inside a co-routine but that didn't help. I am very new to lua and *trying* making games so I really don't know how to improve performance. The fact that the lagginess gets worse and worse seems to suggest memory is not being freed effectively? I assumed this happened automatically. Anyway, any help much appreciated.

After suggestions, I have tried this:

```
Hi, I have tried this:

    local Platform = {}
    local maPart = Platform.part
    local function makePart(pX,pY,pZ)
        maPart = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
        maPart.Position = Vector3.new(pX,pY,pZ)
        maPart.Size = Vector3.new(10,1,10)
        return maPart
    end

    local columns = {}
    local rows = {}

    for i = 1, 12 do
        columns[i] = rows
        table.insert(columns, rows)
        for j = 1, 12 do
            maPart = makePart(i*16,0,j*16)
            rows[j] = maPart
            table.insert(rows, maPart)
        end
    end

    columns[1].[1].BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really blue")
```

As an exercise to see if I can get this new concept for me of 'multi dimensional arrays' to work. The last line doesn't work. How would I access an element inside an array inside an array? tx

Comment: Is this going to be a single player game? If not, what color should a platform be where two players criss cross?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, my idea is that every player only sees the changes in their local machine. The idea is that the colours help you orientate your next move. I am not completely sure how to accomplish this at this point though. Possibly a local script instead of a serverscriptservice one? I wanted to sort the performance issue first. Any suggestions welcome though

Comment: Can you share that troublesome project? If it's not big enough to be considered a product :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor change - move out the loop the construction of new BrickColor. Its value doesn't change across unaffected parts, no reasons to repeatedly create it.

And see if printing lots of debugging information affects the performance, so comment out prints.

Secondly, probably you should reorganize the grid of the blocks into two-dimentional array. So then you don't have to scan all the parts to find the ones that has the same X/Z coordinate. This also will give you the way to quickly find the closest brick, it's trivial on a regular grid.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am sorry to ask, but could you show me what you mean. Taking anything out of the loop is breaking things!

Comment: I think they are suggesting using a nested loop to construct the platforms in a grid, rather than grab them out of the Workspace.

Comment: I mean store the parts in an array of arrays, not in a single table. That way you can get the row/column indices of the closest part by simply scaling/offsetting the player's coordinates. You will get the closest part instantly, regardless of the field size.

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't inside the coroutine, only the connection to the signal is. But, since the heartbeat code is running every single frame, using a coroutine to dispatch the work to a different thread that won't start until the next frame won't help much. So instead of threading, try to look for ways to minimize the computational effort of the function.

Print statements can slow things down, so comment those out when you know the logic works. Calculations with square roots are expensive, so I think the best optimization is to minimize the number of distance checks.

I would recommend making the Heartbeat function act as a more reliable TouchEnded handler, but only have it do work on platforms that know they have a player touching them. Then you can use a part's Touched handler for knowing which platforms have players.

```
-- initialize some script globals
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

-- grab all the platforms and create a table of custom objects with data we care about
local platforms = {}
for _, part in ipairs(game.Workspace:GetDescendants()) do
    if string.sub (v.name, 1, 4) ~= "Part"  then
        continue
    end

    local platformData = {
        Part = part, -- the original object
        Touches = {}, -- a map of players actively touching it
    }

    -- initialize any events on these parts
    part.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
        -- when touched, check which player it is, and hold onto that information
        local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
        if not player then
            warn(string.format("unexpected object touched a platform. Ignoring %s", part.Parent.Name))
            return
        end

        platformData.Touches[player.PlayerId] = player
    end)

    -- hold onto this data
    table.insert(platforms, platformData)
end

-- make a function that updates colors
RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    for _, platform in ipairs(platforms) do
        local isTouched = next(platform.Touches) ~= nil

        -- quick escape for inactive platforms
        if not isTouched then
            continue
        end

        -- check if the previous players are still touching it
        isTouched = false
        for id, player in pairs(platform.Touches) do
            local platPos = platform.Part.Position
            local hrp = player.Character.PrimaryPart
            local charPos = hrp.Position
            local dist = (platPos - charPos).magnitude

            if dist < 6 then
                isTouched = true
            else
                -- this player is no longer touching, remove them
                platform.Touches[id] = nil
            end
        end

        -- update the color of the platforms
        if isTouched then
            platform.Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
        else
            platform.Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really blue")
        end
    end
end)
```

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: This code doesn't highlight all the tiles in the same row and column, I'll make an edit for that. I started typing this answer last night.